# Advice for using argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I am writing a python command line client program to interface with an api. The user uses the client program to run following command and the client program makes following example calls to api

> python run.py --car --> calls method get_all(vehicle_type) which requests-->  /car/all    --< which returns list of all cars
>
> python run.py --van -->  /van/all    --> which returns list of all vans
>
> /car/id/123  --> --> calls method get_by_id(vehicle_type, id) which requests --> returns list of car with id 123

And similar for all others.

> /car/color/red return list of car with color red
>
> /car/model_no/31x  return car with model_no 31x
>
> /van/id/312  returns list of van with id 321

I am using arg parse for this purpose and having trouble properly putting this. Right now, I am doing.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
grp1 = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
grp2 = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()

grp1.add_argument('--car', action='store_const', const='car')
grp1.add_argument('--van', action='store_const', const='van')

grp2.add_argument('--id', help='get by id')
grp2.add_argument('--model_no', help='get by model number')
grp2.add_argument('--color', help='get by color') 

arg_dict = {k:v for k, v in vars(args).items() if v}
```

when I run this code for command.

> python run.py --car --id  123

I get

> {'car' : 'car' , 'id' : '123'}

I am looping through this dict and using getattr to call function by the key name 'get_by_{name}'.format(name = key).
However, my code doesn't looks nice as I have to check if the length is 1 then call get all function and check for vehicle type. Is there a better way to properly use argparse to make code more compact.

Comment: by `grp1 = parser.add(..)` do you possibly mean `grp1.add_argument(...)` ?

Comment: Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find when using mutually_exclusive_groups I frequently make use of the [`dest` option](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#dest) so you have one variable with a dynamic value:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
grp1 = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
grp2 = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()

group_1_options = {"action":"store_const",'dest':"vehicle"}

grp1.add_argument('--car', const="car", **group_1_options)
grp1.add_argument('--van', const='van', **group_1_options)
```

Then for the second group you can use `type` to apply a change when the option is specified, so that it saves a reference to the option text specified:

```
parser.set_defaults(request=("get_all",None))

request_args = {"id":'get by id',
                "model_no":"get by model number",
                "color":"get by color"}

grp2 = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
for arg_name, help_text in request_args.items():
    grp2.add_argument("--"+arg_name, help=help_text, dest="request",
                      type=(lambda x, arg_text=arg_name:(arg_text,x)))
```

Then the request can be retrieved like:

```
def test(argline):
    namespace = parser.parse_args(argline.split())
    kind,value = namespace.request
    print(namespace.vehicle, kind, value)
```

Then you are guaranteed to just have to deal with the `vehicle` and `request` options:

```
>>> test("--van")
van get_all None
>>> test("--car --id 123")
car id 123
>>> test("--model_no 55 --van")
van model_no 55
>>> test("--car --id") #invalid because there is no request value
usage: test.py [-h] (--car | --van)
               [--color REQUEST | --id REQUEST | --model_no REQUEST]
test.py: error: argument --id: expected one argument
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This makes it much more easier. But,  color takes argument though. This one seems to return the request type but i also need request argument, which for example could be red.

Comment: right... so this would definitely simplify the first group but I'm not sure how to simplify the second group.

Comment: wait, is this even what you were looking for or am I going in the complete wrong direction?

Comment: I am just looking for a nice compact way to do it. I think you answer definitely helps. If you have more suggestions (like way you would approach this),  I would be happy to listen.

Comment: Is it possible to get the arguments color, id, model_number as something like NameSpace(vehicle='van', request= {'color' : 'red'})

Comment: @paris_serviola updated answer, personally I'm not a fan of using the `type` option for this kind of thing but it was definitely the cleanest way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

A relatively straight forward way of doing what you want (I think) is:

```
import argparse

def get_all(vehicle_type, *value):   # optional value parameter
    print('all', vehicle_type)

def get_by_id(vehicle_type, id):
    print('id', vehicle_type, id)

def get_by_color(vehicle_type, color):
    print('color', vehicle_type, color)

def get_by_model(vehicle_type, model):
    print('model', vehicle_type, model)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--vehicle_type','-v',choices=['car','van'])
# could be mutually exclusive group with --car and --var

getby_group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
getby_group.add_argument('--id')
getby_group.add_argument('--color')
getby_group.add_argument('--model')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.id:
    get_by_id(args.vehicle_type, args.id)
elif args.color:
    get_by_color(args.vehicle_type, args.color)
elif args.model:
    get_by_model(args.vehicle_type, args.model)
else:
    get_all(args.vehicle_type)
```

You could use `default=argparse.SUPPRESS` to keep `id` out of `args` (like what you do with `arg_dict = {k:v for k, v in vars(args).items() if v}`.  But it easier to test

```
if args.id:
   ...
```

than

```
if hasattr(args,'id'):
    ...
```

or

```
if get(vars,'id',None):
     ...
```

If you really wanted to generate the function name from `args` values you could do a dictionary lookup (`locals()` or a custom dictionary).  Internally `argparse` uses a `registries` dictionary via `parser.register`.

```
fn = locals().get('get_by_%s'%'id')
fn(args.vehicle_type, args.id)
```

The `argparse` docs shows how `parser.set_defaults` can be used to define an `args` attribute as a function.  But that particular use only applies to subparsers.

You could use `const` to set an function, eg

```
getby_group.add_argument('--id',dest='fn',action='store_const', const=get_by_id)
```

Then

```
args.fn(...)
```

would run `get_by_id` function.

< removed a version that uses this `store_const`.  It had problems accepting a value; set edit history for details >

===================

Here's a custom action approach to defining a `fn` attribute and a `value`

```
class GetAction(argparse._StoreAction):
    # barest customization
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        fn=kwargs.pop('fn')
        super(GetAction, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fn = fn 
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        super(GetAction, self).__call__(parser, namespace, values, option_string=None)
        setattr(namespace, 'fn', self.fn)

parser.set_defaults(fn=get_all)  # default action    
getby_group.add_argument('--id',   dest='value', action=GetAction, fn=get_by_id)
getby_group.add_argument('--color',dest='value', action=GetAction, fn=get_by_color)
getby_group.add_argument('--model',dest='value', action=GetAction, fn=get_by_model)
args = parser.parse_args()
args.fn(args.vehicle_type, args.value)
```

BUT - notice that the class definition requires more lines of code than the `if-else` tree.  And took me longer to write.

Comment: the first way is definitely the simplest but the OP is specifically looking for something more compact and your last example fails since it makes `value` required and completely irrelevant to the option specified before it.

Comment: With a custom action class you could set the `fn` attribute as well as take a value.  That just moves the complexity to the parser definition.  Sometimes avoiding a simple `if else` tree isn't worth the effort.

Comment: Oh you were suggesting making a **custom** action class, that was not clear.

Comment: I've worked out a custom action that would define both a `fn` attribute and take a value.

Comment: Honestly I feel like a feature in exclusive mutual group of "the name of the option selected is stored in this variable and the value of that option is stored in this variable" would be a really useful feature, anyway I think the custom action is much easier to expand on as adding an option with the `if/else` would require adding three lines in the most basic case but consistently 1 line with the custom action.